# Changing distance between categories when plotting FacetGrid with error bars

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, errorbar, facet-grid

I am using FacetGrid from Seaborn together with errorbar from Matplotlib to generate a graph that has two categories in the y axis. I want to center the two categories (get them closer to each other and more distant to the margins).

I have tried to change height/aspect to achieve that without success. I am sharing the code below. Thanks!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

cat = ['a','b','a','a','a','b','b','a']      
var=[3,5,4,6,7,5,6,3]       
sd_var = [0.1,0.3,0.1,0.5,0.4,0.2,0.1,0.2]      

df = pd.DataFrame({'cat' : cat, 'var' : var, 'sd_var' : sd_var})

g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, hue="cat", aspect=1, height=6)        
g.map(plt.errorbar, "cat", "var", "sd_var", marker="o",
linestyle='',markersize='6', capsize=4, elinewidth=2)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close to it

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

# replace label with actual number
cat = [1,2,1,1,1,2,2,1]      
var=[3,5,4,6,7,5,6,3]       
sd_var = [0.1,0.3,0.1,0.5,0.4,0.2,0.1,0.2]      

df = pd.DataFrame({'cat' : cat, 'var' : var, 'sd_var' : sd_var})

g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, hue="cat", aspect=1, height=6)        
g.map(plt.errorbar, "cat", "var", "sd_var", marker="o",
linestyle='',markersize='6', capsize=4, elinewidth=2)

# place the ticks at center by widening the plot
plt.xlim((0, 3))
# fix ticks at the number encoding for each class
g.fig.axes[0].xaxis.set_ticks([1, 2])
# name the numbers
g.fig.axes[0].xaxis.set_ticklabels(['a', 'b'])
plt.show()
```

The trick is to make use of relative length of the x-limit and your number encoding for the classes.

[image]